# Can't compile Sass with Grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs, node-sass

I'm new to Grunt and am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSQf10i0_7c&index=5&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j85fkVyCzCMJDfteLtrl_y).

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get Grunt to compile Sass. I keep getting the following when I run `grunt sass`:

> ```
> Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
> >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
> Warning: Task "sass" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.
> ```

- node: v6.11.0,
- npm:  v6.4.1,
- grunt cli: v1.3.2

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "yb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "yb site build",
  "main": "src/js/main.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-sass": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Scott",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   // Configuration
   grunt.initConfig({
      concat: {
         js: {
            src: ['src/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'assets/js/main.js'
         },
         css: {
            src: ['src/**/*.css'],
            dest: 'assets/css/main.css'
         }
      },

      sass: {
         build: {
            files: [{
               src: 'src/sass/test.scss',
               dest: 'assets/css/test.css'
            }]
         }
      }

   });

   // Load Plugins
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

   // Register Tasks
   grunt.registerTask('concat-js', ['concat:js']);
   grunt.registerTask('concat-css', ['concat:css']);
};
```

The [grunt-sass docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass) give a different configuration (which I've also tried), but I still can't get it to compile.

As far as I know, everything is installed. I can't find where I'm going off the rails here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. check ruby with `ruby -v` (install [ruby][1] )
2. Install Sass with sudo `gem install sass` (install [sass][2] )

setting for Grunt Tasks & run `grunt convert-sass`

```
// Load Grunt
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Tasks
  concat: {
     js: {
        src: ['src/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'assets/js/main.js'
     },
     css: {
        src: ['src/**/*.css'],
        dest: 'assets/css/main.css'
     }
  },

    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          sourcemap: 'none'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'src/sass',
          src: ['**/*.scss'],
          dest: 'assets/css',
          ext: '.css'
      }]
      }
    }

  });

  // Load plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

   // Register Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('concat-js', ['concat:js']);
  grunt.registerTask('concat-css', ['concat:css']);
  grunt.registerTask('convert-sass', 'sass');

};
```